# How to call a function inside a div and bind the value it returns to a variable in angular 4

Tags: angular

`<div functionCallHere and bind value here itself></div>`
 Please help how to do it. I want to call a function inside a div and the value which is returned by function is bind with the variable with ngModel

Comment: `ngModel` is used with form controls (input, select, etc). Your question is unusual for 2 reasons: use ngModel with a div, and passing a function to ngModel. Please expand your question otherwise I feel it needs to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use ngModel at div.use innerHtml and assign a function which can return plain html without actionable tags.